# GridDB offline first mode with React Native

Tags: node.js, nosql, griddb

Does GridDB supports offline first mode?

We would like to use it with [React Native](https://en.wikipedia.org) and auto synchronise local and remote databases.

/wiki/React_(JavaScript_library)#React_Native

Answer (score 0):

GridDB doesn't directly support offline first, but most IoT applications use [MQTT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MQTT) (with a MQTT broker and connector server side) to provide enough [QoS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quality_of_service) that will allow offline first transactions.